# Not able to compare columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am using the following SQL code to compare two `nvarchar` columns. But the code is showing incorrect results:

```
SELECT 
    DP.NAME, DP.sid, SU.sid,
    CASE 
       WHEN DP.sid = SU.sid  
          THEN 'TRUE' 
          ELSE 'FALSE' 
    END AS DESDIREDRESULT
FROM 
    #SQLLOGINS DP
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.sysusers SU ON DP.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = SU.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

In the code, I am doing a inner join of a temp table, `#SQLLOGINS`, with `sys.sysusers`. This temp table includes `NAME` and `SID` of `sys.sqllogins`.

I am facing an issue, while both the SID is same, it should be 'TRUE' in the output. Screenshot attached. But it's returning FALSE.

I am not sure where I am wrong here in comparing the SID columns.

[image]

Comment: What are the datatypes of columns `DP.sid` and `SU.sid`?

Comment: Try checking string length for hidden characters. `LEN(string)` Also make sure are on the same `COLLATE`

Comment: `SU.sid` is `varbinary(75)` so as your question says you are using a `nvarchar` for `DP.sid` in your temp table that will be your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the types. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeString VARCHAR(100),SomeBinary VARBINARY(100));

INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('0x1234',0x1234);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES(0x6565,0x6565); --implicit cast!
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES('ee', CAST('ee' AS VARBINARY(100))) --explicit cast!

SELECT *, CASE WHEN SomeString=SomeBinary THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END FROM @mockupTable;
```

The result

```
+----+------------+------------+--------------------+
| ID | SomeString | SomeBinary |                    |
+----+------------+------------+--------------------+
| 1  | 0x1234     | 0x1234     | FALSE              |
+----+------------+------------+--------------------+
| 2  | ee         | 0x6565     | TRUE               |
+----+------------+------------+--------------------+
| 3  | ee         | 0x6565     | TRUE               |
+----+------------+------------+--------------------+
```

What happens here?

The first row looks the same, but isn't, while the 2 and 3 are obviously different but return they are the same?

The reason: The binary value `0x1234` and the string `0x1234` are not the same, although the look as if they were.

Just try `SELECT CAST('0x1234' AS VARBINARY(100))`. The result is `0x307831323334` which is - obviously! - not the same as `0x1234`. It is a list of codes actually: 30 (0), 78 (x), 31 (1), 32 (2), 33 (3), 34 (4).

But in row 2 and 3 you can see, that the binary value of a string can be compared with a real binary. Doing this, you can see that the string `ee` has two small *letter e*, with the ASCII code 65. So `0x6565` translates to `ee`.

Answer (score -1):

There are typically 3 causes of things like this:

1. Hidden characters (line feeds etc)
2. Incompatible data types or code pages
3. Trailing spaces

I suggest you cast/convert both attributes and throw a trim in for good measure.