# Not able to select correct data with varbinary datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am inserting `varbinary` data into a TEMP table. When selecting the TEMP table I am not getting the correct output. Its shows me a different output than what I have inserted.

Output and inserted SID are different. How to solve this

```
CREATE TABLE #SQLLOGINS
(
  NAME NVARCHAR(250),
  SID VARBINARY(MAX)
)    

INSERT INTO #SQLLOGINS (NAME, SID) 
VALUES('Dev_Config_User', CAST('0x010600000000006400000000000000003A93A6F3D52B7949A715D24561FAC3BB' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
INSERT INTO #SQLLOGINS (NAME, SID) 
VALUES('Dev_Smart_user', CAST('0x0106000000000064000000000000000004B76A0393F9E841804C51F60703E036' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
INSERT INTO #SQLLOGINS (NAME, SID) 
VALUES('Dev_Smart2_User', CAST('0x01060000000000640000000000000000883D5E1A9EC11F40B6DBAF657082C780' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))

SELECT * FROM #SQLLOGINS
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Casting it is converting the characters in the string '0x0106...' to binary [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) just remove the quotes and the cast.

Comment: You already appear to have an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57990148/1127428). When someone has already answered, and you need further information, comment on the answer so they can improve their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `CAST` and simply insert the hex values:

```
INSERT INTO #SQLLOGINS (NAME, SID) 
VALUES('Dev_Config_User', 0x010600000000006400000000000000003A93A6F3D52B7949A715D24561FAC3BB)
INSERT INTO #SQLLOGINS (NAME, SID) 
VALUES('Dev_Smart_user', 0x0106000000000064000000000000000004B76A0393F9E841804C51F60703E036)
INSERT INTO #SQLLOGINS (NAME, SID) 
VALUES('Dev_Smart2_User', 0x01060000000000640000000000000000883D5E1A9EC11F40B6DBAF657082C780)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to convert the hex as a string, then use `CONVERT(BINARY, N'string', 1)`:

```sql
INSERT INTO #SQLLOGINS (NAME, SID) 
VALUES('Dev_Smart_user', CONVERT(BINARY, N'0x0106000000000064000000000000000004B76A0393F9E841804C51F60703E036', 1))
```

That should work too.

Comment: And read the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to understand what is happening.